# Laravel, load relationships using JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, laravel, eloquent, relationship

We all know that using the **Eloquent** `with('relation')` function is not doing a **JOIN** , but it's making another query to get the relationship.
Is there a way to make a single query using **JOIN** so we can reduce our MySQL queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to use JOIN when using Eloquent objects. This is how Eloquent work - it doesn't use joins, it uses separate queries to get related data. So if you want to use joins, you won't be able to use Eloquent objects.

Comment: You can use joins if you would like. The resulting attributes on the model may not be what you want though.  If you do the join below through the model you will have a model with attributes that dont belong to it. So in that regard I suppose you wouldn't want that.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a **VIEW** in database, and then, create a model in your app. Updated data in VIEW is automatically updated in the related tables. Could be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah something like this if you want to do a left join ( use `->join()` for a simple inner join)

```
 $query = DB::table('product');
 $query->leftJoin('user', 'product.seller_id', '=','user.user_id');
 return $query->get();
```

See the query builder docs for further details: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins

Comment: Yes but this way we can't get our Model object.

Comment: That's right. Once you've used an ORM you can't do a join anymore if that's what you mean. The query builder allows us to make more customized queries.

You can do eager loading if you want but that will still take 2 queries. If you want one query you have to do an explicit join, no work around it.